# Secret Access Key from AWS for MTurkR

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I am attempting to set up the MTurkR R Package for the first time which requires Access Keys, both "Access Key Id" and "Secret Access Key" from AWS see: http://polmeth.wustl.edu/methodologist/tpm_v20_n2.pdf

However Amazon recently "removed the ability to retrieve existing secret access keys for your AWS (root) account." [see here](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx1DYHFAOOH47DK/Important-change-to-how-you-manage-your-AWS-account-s-access-keys)

I tried creating an IAM User and using their Access Key within the `credentials()` command, but get the following error:

```
Error (AWS.MechanicalTurk.UnacceptableIdentity):
AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) user accounts cannot be used for Amazon 
Mechanical Turk.
```

Is there any way around this issue? Do I have to wait for a package update?

Comment: Did you find a way around this issue?

Comment: I talked to the maintainter of the package and he said:
Thanks for your email. Unfortunately MTurk doesn't work with IAM. So
you'll have to create an access key and secret key (details on how to
do it are here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/managing-aws-access-keys.html).
You can't retrieve an old secret key, but you can create a new keypair
(without deleting a previous one) at which point you'll have one-time access to the secret key. AWS doesn't seem to invest a lot of
resources in the MTurk API, so I suspect this will remain the only
authentication method for some time.

Comment: An update on this: In December 2015, [AWS announced](http://mechanicalturk.typepad.com/blog/2015/12/introducing-mechanical-turk-api-support-for-iam-credentials.html) that IAM is now supported on MTurk.